# is there way to write data in CSV file using jmx script in Azure load testing?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, jmeter, load-testing

I have added beanshell postprocessor in sampler to write data in CSV file and it is working fine in Jmeter. But when I uploaded same jmx script in Azure load testing and ran it, I don't see any CSV file where my response data is added.

**Logs:**
WARN o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore
WARN c.a.c.j.j.c.MALTListener: TEST ENDED EVENT - uploading jmeter.log file

Comment: Did this work for you? We are facing same issue. Instead of writing to csv, we are reading from .xlsx

Answer (score 0):

1. When JMeter is not doing what it is supposed to be doing first thing you should check is [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
2. We cannot even assume what could be wrong without seeing your code
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
4. I haven't seen your code but I don't think using scripting for saving data is a good idea due to [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (when multiple threads are concurrently writing into the same file) which will result in data corruption or loss so I would rather go for one of the below options:

   - Use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property to add the values you need to save to the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles)
   - Amend JMeter [Result File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) to store what you need to store to the .jtl results file (or alternatively use a separate listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) or [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/)). See [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter) article for more details.